# Bounded derivative imply convergence

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ is a $C^1$ function in $(0,\infty)$ such that $f'(x)$ is bounded in $(0,\infty)$. Does $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ converges when $x\rightarrow\infty$? I guess it may be have a counterexample but I have not found one.

Comment: By "converges" do you mean "has a finite limit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider for instance $$f(x)=\frac12(x+1)\left(\sin\ln(1+x)-\cos\ln(1+x)\right)=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt2}\sin\left(\ln(1+x)-\frac\pi4\right)$$

Comment: How do you get to this conterexample?

Comment: @TitoEliatron I had the idea of somehow interpolating continuously a function $g$ which is $1$ for a while, then $-1$ for a much longer while, then $1$ for a yet longer while and so on, and ultimately have $f$ be its integral. Then, not to do the usual "interpolate this" which I have grown rather bored of, I tried to inspect with WA if something like $g=\sin\sqrt t$ worked; then I tried $\sin \ln(1+x)$ and, much to my surprise, I saw that its antiderivatives are elementary.

Comment: $f(x)=x\sin (\ln (x+1))$ works equally fine.

Comment: Thank you @Gae.S.